# Eclipse: Not pointing to the correct Git Directory

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm having a lot of issues trying to set up my Git Repo. I'm going through the "Clone Git Repository" option and provided the right URI, password, etc.

However, as soon as I click next (see image 2 below) - I keep getting this same error "java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\Users\eluu\%d.ssh".

This is the wrong directory I want git to reference my SSH. Even though I have correctly set my SSH2 home directory (image 1 below), it still gives me this error.

I've tried adding and renaming my files into "C:\Users\eluu\%d.ssh" with no luck. I've used Git Bash before and I believe this may be the problem with internal system settings. Uninstalling Git Bash did not help...

Please help me!

[image]

[image]